# Is there a way to record audio and start listening on the click, store on our local machine and convert that from speech to text?

Tags: android, react-native, speech-to-text, voice-recognition, azure-language-understanding

Is there a way to record audio and start listening on the click, stop automatically when the user stops speaking , store that recorded audio in our local machine and convert that speech to text and send the text string to the LUIS(Microsoft) API  using React Native(0.60) ?

Comment: you can use https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio package for record audio, after that you can save it in storage with https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs package. in final you have to write native module for call  LUIS(Microsoft) API in react native

Comment: I tried github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio , it seems to be not working,Any other suggestions are greatly appreciated .

Comment: I've used it and it's ok for recording audio, what is that problem?

Comment: can you guide me further on this please, I am really stuck, pulling my hair all over
can we get in touch ?